# If my fiance gifts me $18K and we get married before the end of the year will the gift tax apply?

Tags: united-states, gift-tax

My fiance and I are trying to buy a house. The loan is in my name, but he would like to pay for $18K worth of closing costs. The plan is to close the deal by 10/21/2013. If we get married by the end of this year, will the gift tax apply?

Answer (score 11):

For your status during the year, the date of your wedding doesn't matter. Jan 1 or Dec 31, you are considered 'married' for the year. In this situation, no gift tax issue applies.